# getSessionAsSigner is null while using frostillic.us controller classes

Tags: java, jsf, xpages

I will start by saying that:

- I'm using ODA (godmode,khan,marcel).
- I'm the only code signer.
- sessionAsSigner is working the first time I load an XPage that calls it.
- sessionAsSigner becomes null after I reload a page (cmd + R) but not when I'm subsequently referencing it in any action during in the context of the viewScope lifetime.
- I'm implementing [@Gidgerby 's concept of controller classes](https://frostillic.us/f.nsf/posts/more-on--controller--classes)

I would also add that **sessionAsSigner works consistently if I just prepare a simple XPage that does the following**:

```
<p>
    <xp:text value="session: #{session.effectiveUserName}" />
</p>

<p>
    <xp:text value="sessionAsSigner: #{sessionAsSigner.effectiveUserName}" />
</p>
```

Now, I am not using SSJS. I'm JSF/EL oriented as much as I can, according to my current knowledge. So, the way I access Domino back-end is unconventional for a Domino XPages programmer.

**Where I can't get getSessionAsSigner to work consistently is when I try to do the above mentioned thing...**

Here is my XPage controller (backing bean):

```
 public class TestPageController extends StandardXPageController {

 private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

 private AnswerDTO answer;

 public TestPageController() {
    loadQuotation();
 }

 private void loadQuotation() {
     AnswerDAO answerDAO = Factory.createAnswerDAO();

     try {
        answer = answerDAO.read("doc_id");

     } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

 public AnswerDTO getAnswer() {
     return answer;
 }
}
```

AnswerDTO is a POJO. I'm using the DAO/DTO design pattern.
The AnswerDAO implementation - with simplified code (wrap method is just a mere mapping of fields) - as following:

```
public class AnswerDAODominoImpl implements AnswerDAO {

 private transient Session s;
 private transient Database db;

 private Session getSession() {
    if (s == null) {
        s = XSPUtil.getCurrentSessionAsSigner();
    }

    return s;
 }

 private Database getDatabase() throws NotesException {
    if (db == null) {
        db = getSession().getDatabase("server_name", "server_path");
    }

    return db;
 }

 public AnswerDTO read(String id) throws Exception {
    Database db = getDatabase();

    return wrap(db.getDocumentByID(id));
 }
}
```

This is the ViewHandler class:

```
public class ViewHandler extends ViewHandlerExImpl {

public ViewHandler(final javax.faces.application.ViewHandler delegate) {
    super(delegate);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public UIViewRoot createView(final FacesContext context, final String pageName) {
    try {
        // pageName is the XPage name prefixing the slash (e.g. "/home")
        String pageClassName = pageName.substring(1);
        Class<? extends XPageController> controllerClass = null;

        try {
            controllerClass = (Class<? extends XPageController>) context.getContextClassLoader().loadClass(
                    "com.sea.xsp.controller." + StringUtil.getProperCaseString(pageClassName) + "PageController");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
            controllerClass = StandardXPageController.class;
        }

        XPageController controller = controllerClass.newInstance();
        Map<String, Object> requestScope = (Map<String, Object>) context.getApplication().getVariableResolver().resolveVariable(context, "requestScope");
        requestScope.put("controller", controller);
        UIViewRootEx root = (UIViewRootEx) super.createView(context, pageName);
        root.getViewMap().put("controller", controller);
        requestScope.remove("controller");

        //          MethodBinding beforePageLoad = context.getApplication().createMethodBinding("#{controller.beforePageLoad}", new Class[] { PhaseEvent.class });
        //          root.setBeforePageLoad(beforePageLoad);

        return root;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return super.createView(context, pageName);
}
}
```

Basically, what the viewhandler does is to check the existence of a java class which prefix is the XPage name itself.

eg. **test**.xsp = something.something.package.**Test**PageController

This approach allows me to forget about declaring specific XPage related classes as generic managed beans in the faces-config.xml
All the XPages will get an easy handle to their corresponding backing bean that will always be named **#{controller}**

Now, having that being said if I simply write the following in an XPage, everything will work the first time, but not a second time (getSession() is OK, getSessionAsSigner is null), never ever again. I need to push a new change to the database (design update after any change to the java code and **xsp.application.forcefullrefresh=true**) and it will work again, but, again, just the first time the page is loaded.

```
<p>
    <xp:text value="answer doc id: #{controller.answer.id}" />
</p>
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is possibly due to a bug we discovered a bit ago with the XPages runtime, somehow related to `ClassLoader#loadClass`. It turns out that using that as you do (and as I used to) can cause `sessionAsSigner` to stop working after the first page load. The fix is to switch to `Class.forName(String, true, ClassLoader)`: https://github.com/jesse-gallagher/XPages-Scaffolding/commit/d65320fd6d98ff2fbaa814a95eb38ce7bad5a81d

Comment: That.Was.It!

Many thanks! sessionAsSigner is finally stable!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you run through in Java debugger? Is it going into `XSPUtil.getSessionAsSigner()` the second time round?

I tend to use `ExtLibUtil.resolveVariable()` to get a handle on sessionAsSigner if godmode is enabled. Alternatively, there's `org.openntf.domino.utils.Factory.getSessionAsSigner()`. Do those give a different result?

(In RC3 that is still be available but is marked deprecated in favour of `Factory.getSession(SessionType.SIGNER)` because we're supporting implementations outside XPages, so there are more session types involved.)